# When creating an object of a subtype based on an object of a supertype, how to make sure I manually provide only the missing properties?

Tags: typescript

I get a json with user details from an api (`readUserFromApi`). The api also provides the type of its response (`interface User`) and this interface is automatically imported in my code base when/if api updates its response structure.

I read the json from api and add other useful properties, creating `detailedUser`. When creating `detailedUser` I want to provide **only** the properties not provided by api. In the future, if api will also provide a `name` for user, the `interface User` in my code will be automatically updated and I want a typescript error telling me I don't need to manually provide a `name` when building `detailedUser` because `name` would already come from api.

I have a solution, see `dummyVar`, but there should be a more elegant one...

([code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwXAdgHgIIBooCEB8UAvFAN4BQUUA2gApQCWKUA1hCHAGZQZQBkrdlzwBdAFw86IqAB88UgNzkAvuXKhIUAKIAPAIYBjYABsQaACo4AqlAg7gEFABMAzlHOES5-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-cDyCAA))

```js
type Common<A, B> = {
  [P in keyof A & keyof B]: A[P] | B[P];
}

type Exactly<T, U extends T> = T & Record<Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>, never>

interface User {
    id: number
}

interface DetailedUser {
    id: number
    name: string
    sex: string
}

const readUserFromApi = () => ({id: 1})
const user: User = readUserFromApi()

const detailedUser: DetailedUser = {
    // I want an error if by mistake I provide a default value for `id`,
    // I dont have to do that, `id` comes from `user`
    name: 'default name',
    sex: 'f',
    ...user
}

// when interface User changes in the future and get a new property `name`,
// line below will trigger a typescript error - as I expect
declare const dummyVar: Exactly<Common<typeof user, {name: any, sex: any}>, {}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `DetailedUser` type we can get an error directly in the type if  we use a type alias instead of an interface. There should be no practical difference for simple types such as this object type.

```
interface User {
    id: number
    //name: string // comment this and you get an error below
}
type SafeExtend<TBase, TExt extends Record<Extract<keyof TBase, keyof TExt>, never>> = TBase & TExt
type DetailedUser = SafeExtend<User, {
    name: string
    sex: string
}>
```

`SafeExtend` will take the base interface (`User`) and a type that contains any extra fields you want to add. If the added fields are already in the base interface you will get an error.

For the second part, where you want to get an error in spread if you specify the field, I don't think this is possible using spread. You can do it if you use a function instead:

```
function safeSpread<TBase, TExt>(base: TBase, ext: TExt & Record<Extract<keyof TBase, keyof TExt>, never> ) {
    return {
        ...base, 
        ...ext
    };
}

const detailedUser: DetailedUser = safeSpread(user, {
    name: 'default name',
    sex: 'f',
    id: 0 // error
})
```

Comment: This solution does raise an error when you try to overwrite `id` using a non-undefined value (`id: 0` raises error), but doesn't raise error for undefined (`id: undefined` raises no error). This behavior is fixed if instead of `ext: TExt & Partial<Record<Extract<keyof TBase, keyof TExt>, never>>` we use `ext: TExt & Record<Extract<keyof TBase, keyof TExt>, never>`. I'm wondering if there was a particular reason you used `Partial`.

Comment: @awho yeah, fair enough, the `Partial` should not be there, it was a mistake